# What are the normal modes of a vertical rope?

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves

Closely related to [this question on traveling waves on a hanging rope](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2088/will-a-wave-packet-undergo-dispersion-when-traveling-down-a-hanging-rope), I would also like to know what the normal modes are on a rope that hangs vertically, fixed at both ends.

Tension in the rope increases with height, so I expect that the wavelength of standing waves decreases as we move up, and nodes are  clustered somewhat more towards the top of the rope than the bottom.  Is this correct?

The wave equation I found was (**note**: important typo corrected)

$$\frac{\partial^2{x}}{\partial t^2} = g \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} + \frac{T_0+\lambda g y}{\lambda} \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial y^2}$$

so mathematically, my question is about how to find the eigenfunctions of this equation with the boundary conditions $x(0) = x(h) = 0$ with $h$ the height of the ceiling.

(I was able to [locate a reference](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1998PhTea..36..108G), but don't have access to it.)

Comment: Does this [link](http://tpt.aapt.org/resource/1/phteah/v36/i2/p108_s1) work? If not, I'll upload the file somewhere.

Comment: @Raskolnikov No, that link is behind a pay wall.  However, if I make a trip to the university library today I can access the article from there.

Comment: @Keenan You are correct that I left out a factor of y, but that doesn't make it nonlinear.  I'll fix the difEq.

Comment: Your differential equation is incorrect. There should be a factor of y in the d^2x/dy^2 term, so it's not just a harmonic oscillator equation with constant coefficients. (Still linear though, you're right.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I want to try to give a solution to your equation using a **separation ansatz** of the form
$$x(y,t) = T(t)\cdot Y(y)$$

We find
$$\frac{T''}{T} = \frac{1}{Y}\left( gY' + \left(\frac{T_0 + \lambda g y}{\lambda}\right) Y'' \right)$$

Both sides do depend on different variables, hence the given equation must equal a constant, say $-\omega_n^2$.

We see directly that the fundamental system for $T$ can be stated as oscillations (if this notation is convenient for you):
$$eig(T) = \{ \sum_n \left[ e^{\mathrm{i}\omega_n t}, e^{-\mathrm{i}\omega_n t} \right]\}$$

### New solution for Y

The differential equation for $Y$ now takes the form
$$ \frac{\omega_n^2}{g} Y + Y' + \left(\frac{T_0}{\lambda} + y\right) Y'' = 0$$

and it is obvious that one should first of all make a substitution of the form
$$z = \frac{T_0}{\lambda} + y$$

Such that we find with $Y(y) = Z(z)$

$$\frac{\omega_n^2}{g} Z + Z' + z Z'' = 0$$

The solution to this equation are indeed **Bessel functions**

$$eig(Z) = \{J_0\left(2\omega_n \sqrt{z/g} \right) , Y_0\left( 2\omega_n \sqrt{z/g}\right) \}$$

So, finally

$$x{(t,y)}=\sum_n e^{\{+,-\}\mathrm{i}\omega_n t}\left[ a_n J_0 \left( 2\omega_n \sqrt{\frac{T_0 + \lambda y}{\lambda g}} \right) + b_n Y_0 \left( 2\omega_n \sqrt{\frac{T_0 + \lambda y}{\lambda g}} \right) \right]$$

The overall solution is then given due to the starting and boundary conditions you specified. Since this is a discussion on its own, I will leave this for the [other thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2088/will-a-wave-packet-undergo-dispersion-when-traveling-down-a-hanging-rope) :)
Sincerely

Robert

Comment: @Robert Thanks!  I remember this method from my quantum mechanics course now that you've written it out.  All your calculations look correct to me.

Comment: @Mark: You're welcome :) As you can see, this was straight forward. Now, actually, comes the tricky part: the interpretation of the solution at hand.

Comment: This solution is incorrect because the original differential equation is incorrect. The eigenfunctions are not sinusoids, but Bessel functions.

Comment: @Keenan You are right, there was a typo.  @Robert Sorry - that made you do all the work on the wrong equation.

Comment: @Mark: I updated my answer due to the new equation. I hope I might find the time to do as well for the other thread :) Greets

Comment: @Robert That's more like it. As you said, a_n and b_n are determined by both initial conditions and boundary conditions, and omega_n needs to be determined too. I was trying to find the relationship between a_n, b_n, and omega_n to give the actual normal modes.

Comment: @Keenan: With respect to calculation errors, the given formulation are the eigenfunctions of the differential equation (and thus the normal modes). $a_n$ and $b_n$ are to describe the state of the system; one could call them "modal amplitudes". The $\omega_n$ are the "allowed eigenenergies" of the system end related via a dispersion relation I give in the other thread. From the mathematical standpoint, there should not be so much to add, the physical interpretation is another issue :)

Comment: @RobertFilter it's my first time seeing the notation you used to write "the set of eigenfunctions of T(t)", is that your personal notation or is it common in some field? Because it definitely feels logical to me.

Answer (score 2):

The normal modes are related to Bessel functions.

[I made an error when I first submitted this answer which I am about to correct.]

Here is a web page discussing the free-hanging version of the problem: [The Hanging Chain](http://mysite.du.edu/~jcalvert/math/hchain.htm)

And here is the oldest journal reference I can find, though still much later than the first solution of the problem, which was in the 18th century: [American Journal of Physics 18:405](http://dx.doi.org/10.1119/1.1932623)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error in the differential equation, but I don't think the corrected one is nonlinear.  Bessel's equation is linear, of course.

Comment: I updated my answer due to the new equation. Is this along your lines of thought? Sincerely